# How to normalize image in tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I applied transformation during training phase in pytorch then I convert my model to run in tensorflow.js. It is working fine but got wrong predictions as I didn't apply same transformation.

```
test_transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.Resize(size=(224, 224)),
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
    torchvision.transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
```

I am able to resize image but not able to normalize. how can I do that?

Update:-

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        {% load static %}
       async function load_model(){
            const model = await tf.loadGraphModel("{% static 'disease_detection/tfjs_model_2/model.json' %}");
            console.log(model);
            return model;
        }

        function loadImage(src){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = src;
                img.onload = () => resolve(tf.browser.fromPixels(img, 3));
                img.onerror = (err) => reject(err);
            });
        }

        

        function resizeImage(image) {

            return tf.image.resizeBilinear(image, [224, 224]).sub([0.485, 0.456, 0.406]).div([0.229, 0.224, 0.225]);

        }

        function batchImage(image) {
            
            const batchedImage = image.expandDims(0);  
            //const batchedImage = image; 
            return batchedImage.toFloat();
        }

        function loadAndProcessImage(image) {
            //const croppedImage = cropImage(image);
            const resizedImage = resizeImage(image);
            const batchedImage = batchImage(resizedImage);
            return batchedImage;
        }


        let model =  load_model();
       model.then(function (model_param){
            loadImage('{% static 'disease_detection/COVID-19 (97).png' %}').then(img=>{
             let imge = loadAndProcessImage(img);
             const t4d = tf.tensor4d(Array.from(imge.dataSync()),[1,3,224,224])
                console.log(t4d.dataSync());
             let prediction = model_param.predict(t4d);
             let v = prediction.argMax().dataSync()[0]
             console.log(v)
        })
       })
```

I tried this code but it is not normalizing image properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()** converts PIL Image or numpy array in the range of 0 to 255 to a float tensor os shape (channels x Height x Width) in the range 0.0 to 1.0 . To convert in the range 0.0 to 1.0 it divide each element of tensor by 255. So, execute same in tensorflowJS I done as follows -

```js
img = tf.image.resizeBilinear(img, [224, 224]).div(tf.scalar(255))
img = tf.cast(img, dtype = 'float32');
```

- **torchvision.transforms.Normalize()** normalize a tensor image with mean and standard deviation. Given mean: (mean[1],...,mean[n]) and std: (std[1],..,std[n]) for n channels, this transform will normalize each channel of the input tensor i.e., output[channel] = (input[channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel] . I didn't find any such function in tensorflowJS. So, I seperately normalized each channel and combined them again.

Complete function is as follows -

```js
function imgTransform(img){
            img = tf.image.resizeBilinear(img, [224, 224]).div(tf.scalar(255))
            img = tf.cast(img, dtype = 'float32');

            /*mean of natural image*/
           let meanRgb = {  red : 0.485,  green: 0.456,  blue: 0.406 }

           /* standard deviation of natural image*/
           let stdRgb = { red: 0.229,  green: 0.224,  blue: 0.225 }

            let indices = [
                        tf.tensor1d([0], "int32"),
                        tf.tensor1d([1], "int32"),
                        tf.tensor1d([2], "int32")
            ];

           /* sperating tensor channelwise and applyin normalization to each chanel seperately */
           let centeredRgb = {
               red: tf.gather(img,indices[0],2)
                        .sub(tf.scalar(meanRgb.red))
                        .div(tf.scalar(stdRgb.red))
                        .reshape([224,224]),
               
               green: tf.gather(img,indices[1],2)
                        .sub(tf.scalar(meanRgb.green))
                        .div(tf.scalar(stdRgb.green))
                        .reshape([224,224]),
               
               blue: tf.gather(img,indices[2],2)
                        .sub(tf.scalar(meanRgb.blue))
                        .div(tf.scalar(stdRgb.blue))
                        .reshape([224,224]),
           }
          

            /* combining seperate normalized channels*/
            let processedImg = tf.stack([
                centeredRgb.red, centeredRgb.green, centeredRgb.blue
            ]).expandDims();
           return processedImg;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though I am not too much acquainted with pytorch documentation, a quick look at it shows that the first parameter for `Normalize` is for the mean of the dataset and the second parameter is for the standard deviation.

To normalize using these two parameters with tensorflow.js, the following can be used

```
tensor.sub([0.485, 0.456, 0.406]).div([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
```

But the tensor values should be in the range of 0 to 1 by dividing it to 255 after the resize operation. The whole compose operation will look as the following

```
tf.image.resizeBilinear(image, [224, 224]).div(255)
  .sub([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
  .div([0.229, 0.224, 0.225]);
```

Comment: I tried this but still did not get correct predictions.

Comment: What are the operations performed by pytorch `Normalize` ?

Comment: it is the same operation as you mentioned.  (x[channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel].

Comment: I just check values by printing in console so, it is not normalizing all pixels. there are total 224 x 224 x 3 = 150,528 values but from them only 1343 getting normalize.

Comment: The broadcasting is applied to all the tensor values. I don't see why it will applied to only a subset of the tensor. You were missing to divide the resulting tensor after the resize first by 255